# ld: warning: -no_pie ignored for arm64

Tags: ios, ldflags

I  used "-no_pie" for LDFLAGS , but prompt: "ld: warning: -no_pie ignored for arm64".

then I use otool to check the binary ,there is no PIE flag with V7 and V7S cpusubtype,but still in ARM64,is the ld  don't support -no_pie for ARM64?

Answer (score 2):

This came up for me on an older ObjC project when I upped the Deployment Target from 9.0 to 10.0.  It only occurred when I archived the project or when I ran it on a physical device.  To removed the warning, I set the Build Setting 'Generate Position-Dependent Executable' to 'No'.  It was previously set to 'Yes'.